# [Angular]Programatic Pipe creation?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I would like to create the custom dynamic angular(7.2.2) Pipe.

Eg: User will write the code something like below (User might have to pass the parameter too, still yet to figure out ideal way of sending params.)

```
var myPage={};
   myPage.registerPipe('myPipe', function myPipeFun(parama1, param2){});
```

Now what I want to do is above snippet should convert into angular pipe.

Eg: Below code I should be able to generate, Is it possible to generate the Pipe code angular something like below ?

```
import {
    Injector,
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class myPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    transform(value: any, pipeToken: any, pipeArgs: any[]): any {
       myPipeFun(value, ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible in Angular.

Rather, I would suggest creating a Universal `Pipe`

**First way**

`Pipe` get a callback function as second argument

```
export class UniversalPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, callBackFun): string {
        console.log(value);
        return callBackFun();
    }
}
```

and you can pass dynamic `callback` function to this Universal `Pipe` from your component.

```
<p>
  {{'Start editing to see some magic happen' | universalPipe: myFun}}
</p>
```

**Second way**

You can have all your functions definition in the Pipe itself and pass the type instead of `callback` function to Universal `Pipe` and execute the corresponding function

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prabhat-angular-dynamic-pipes) project